# Recognize canadian user based on web browser settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, internationalization

How can I determine if user is Canadian based on web browser settings?

I'm using Asp.net 2.0.

Comment: You can likely determine if a user is in Canada.  Determining if they are actually a Canadian is a different story...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining if "user is Canadian," is a pretty ambiguous statement. You can determine if a user's browser culture is set to something Canadian by inspecting `HttpRequest.UserLanguages`. Canadian English is `en-CA`, Canadian French is `fr-CA`.

If you're trying to determine if a user is actually sitting in Canada, the best you could hope for is to attempt to resolve location based on their IP, but this isn't going to be reliable. [Here's](http://www.hostip.info/use.html) a publically available serivce for doing that.

Comment: Just an FYI. Many canadians (such as myself) set our computer setting to "EN-US" which prevents some poorly coded applications from doing strange things (due to our reversed d/m/yyyy date format primarily). Is easier to spell colour like the US then to deal with many other issues. Also for example it is rare to see a server configured with canadian regional settings, especially SQL Servers.

Comment: +1 to above point. Also note that some browsers such as Firefox install with en_US as default (including here in UK).